# how to use WCF Service in Lightswitch desktop app?

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

Im new to Lightswitch and would highly appreciate if someone could advise on the following.
I have Lightswitch Desktop application and WCF Service application in one solution. I would like to add WCF service to LS Client. Im simply adding new Service Reference, however I cannot access it in my code. `LightSwitchApplication.ServiceReferenceName` is not found. Is it possible to access it somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, Add a New Project to the existing LightSwitch project.
2. Create a Class Library called WCF_RIA_Project.
3. Delete the Class1.cs file that is automatically created.
4. Add a New Item to WCF_RIA_Project.
5. Add a Class called WCF_RIA_Service.cs.
6. Right-click on References and select Add References to add the following references to the WCF_RIA_Project

   - System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
   - System.Configuration
   - System.Data.Entity
   - System.Runtime.Serialization
   - System.Web
   - System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server

You also need to check this link, hope it helps for you.
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx